# jQuery slider flickering problem if slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, flicker

Hey, I've a tricky problem with a slider I've created in jQuery. After finish it I realize that there is a flickering of the sliding images cross-browser (except ie9). I would like to upload the slider but cant find a button, so I post the script here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can't upload scripts on SO, so please set up a demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

On jquery js find this code and switch this

```
// Simple 'hide' function
hide: function() {
// Remember where we started, so that we can go back to it later
this.options.orig[this.prop] = jQuery.style( this.elem, this.prop );
this.options.hide = true;

// Begin the animation
if ($.browser.msie){
this.custom(this.cur(), 1);
}
else{
this.custom(this.cur(), 0);
}

},
```